# Simple php program displaying no output or error msg

Tags: php

This is my first program in oop php. Its very simple where i would like to add a numerical value to a variable. And program must output 2.

```
 <?php
    class MyClass  
    {  
        public $a = 1;  

        public function abc()  
        {  
            if ($a=1){
                $a+1;   
            }  
        }   
    }  

    $obj = new MyClass;  

    echo $obj->abc;  
    ?>
```

Comment: No it must not.  But you should get a lot of warnings and notices and even errors. This needs basic debugging first, enable error reporting to the highest level possible, log errors and track the error log. Refer to the PHP reference of your choice to learn about error reporting and logging.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to gview's answer:

```
if ($a=1){
    $a+1;   
}
```

Should be:

```
if ($a == 1){
    $a = $a + 1;   
}
```

The `=` operator is for assignment, not for comparisons.

Comment: might want to add something about returning the value for $a

Answer (score 2):

The abc() function does not return anything.  Thus you get no output.  If you add:

```
return $a;
```

You'll get something in the echo.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning your results

```
public function abc()  
{  
   if ($a==1){
      $a++;   
   }  

   return $a;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to return the value from abc()

```
 public function abc()  
        {  
            if ($a=1){
                $a+1;   
            }  
            return $a;
        }
```